# Regex between two strings - include last string

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to pull all domains out of a text file.  They may have a special character at the beginning (like a font tag).

so far:
(?<=>).*?(?=com|net)

Text I'm searching:

> thisdomain.com fake text >thatdomain.net

It is currently finding "thisdomain and thatdomain but of course it's cutting off the domain extension.  I've dug through regex docs for about an hour and can't find a way to search between the > and .com with out cutting off the .com.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Its not find `thisdomain`

Comment: In other words you want to pull domains that are not in html tags => use an html parser. But I can't help you anymore, the weasel is back in the attic, I have to fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
(?<=>).*?(?:com|net)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/DSue4R/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    com                      'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    net                      'net'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

Comment: Thanks man - don't know how i missed that, started off that way

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not matching `.com` is because this part `(?=com|net)` is an assertion which is non consuming.

Instead you can just match either `.com` or `.net` including the dot preventing to match for example `>clarinet` or `>romcom`

```
(?<=>)\S+\.(?:com|net)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the left of the current position

  - `>` Match literally
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\S+` Match 1 or more non whitespace characters
- `\.(?:com|net)` Match either `.com` or `.net`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5DyreN/1).

Without using lookarounds, you can also use a capture group and match the `>`

```
>(\S+\.(?:com|net))
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/31Z7BG/1).